# Consuming lot of data by android os

Tags: rooting

My device is Micromax a110q. I rooted it and changed my rom to sony pure xperia z2. After changing my rom the data is much more consuming by android os. So help me how to reduce data..

Answer (score 0):

Restrict background data of your android os (in `settings -> data usage`). Hope it helps

Comment: I do so but it consuming data and i want to explain briefly my device is rooted and i changed my rom from micromax a110q to xperia z2. So can you help me how to reduce data consumed by android os